# Router file transffer

Tags: linux, telnet, router, file-transfer, busybox

I need to make a script in a router, to do a WOL to a NAS machine.

The problem is that, router refuses all connections except telnet. 
It is D-link router, from a service provider.

I can login to it, and it has busybox installed. Here are commands list of busybox:
[image]

The problem here is that there is no usual commands like scp, for example, even vi doesn't work to create a file.

So how can I possible download the file?

The sftp or ftp or anything else except telnet doesn't work also.

If someone has any idea it would be appreciated! Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the existing commands on your router you can create the script using below commands:

```
echo 'your script' >> somefile
```

Put a semicolon at the end of each line for EOL. But you need to have permission to execute the script. use touch command to create file as `touch xyz.txt` and see the file permission.